# how post feed entry with publish restriction?

Tags: facebook, post

[image]

```
FB.ui({ method: 'feed',
        name: name,
        link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/my-app/',
        picture: 'app-picture',
        caption: 'this is only for me',
        privacy: { value: 'SELF' }},
    function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            // Post was published
            alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
            alert('Post was not published.');
        }
        return true;
    }
);
```

not working

Answer (score 1):

resolved:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
    message: 'message',
    name: 'name test',
    caption: 'caption',
    privacy: { 'value':'CUSTOM','friends':'SELF'} },
    function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```